# Trying to capture value within a captured value

Tags: regex, ruby, fluent-bit

I am trying to parse data from a line like this

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, IP: 111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333\r\n adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod\r\n tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"
```

I am trying to capture the values like this:

- message: `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, IP: 111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333\r\n adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod\r\n tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"`
- ip: `"111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333"`

There can be arbitrary many IPs, including zero.

I am using fluent-bit with a single regex. This is an example of a fluent-bit parser definition:

```
[PARSER]
Name syslog-rfc3164
Format regex
Regex /^\<(?<pri>[0-9]+)\>(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$/
Time_Key    time
Time_Format %b %d %H:%M:%S
Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
Time_Keep   On
```

Thanks to Cary and Aleksei here is the solution:

```
\A(?<whole>.*?((?<=IP: )(?<ip>(?<four_threes>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?:, \g<four_threes>)*)).*?)\z
```

https://rubular.com/r/Kgh5EXMCA0lkew

***EDIT***

I realized that some strings don't have the "IP:..." pattern in them which give me a parsing error.

```
string1: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, IP: 111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333\r\n adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod\r\n tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"

string2: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \r\n adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod\r\n tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"
```

I tried applying *(0 or more) to the ip group name match but i was not able to make it work. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: The initial string you have is not **a line**, its **lines**.

Comment: @sawa ok so lets say its a string. I want to capture that whole string and also capture the IPs within that string but i need them to be captured in 2 different values/tags. Does it makes more sense?

Comment: off-topic: @nomad, I have some thoughts about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514390/how-to-prevent-echo-command-to-execute-commands-in-bash-script but the question is deleted and I can't comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = 'Lorem, IP: 111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333\r\n adipiscing'
```

```
r = /
    \A                     # match the beginning of the string
    (?<whole>              # begin named group 'whole' 
      .*?                  # match >= 0 characters 
      (?<ip>               # begin named group 'ip'
        (?<four_threes>    # begin a named group 'four_threes'
          \d{1,3}          # match 1-3 digits
          (?:              # begin a non-capture group
            \.             # match a period
            \d{1,3}        # match 1-3 digits
          ){3}             # close non-capture group and execute same 3 times
        )                  # close capture group 'four_threes'
        (?:                # begin a non-capture group
          ,\p{Space}       # match ', '
          \g<four_threes>  # execute subexpression named 'four_threes'
        )*                 # close non-capture group and execute same >= 0 times
      )                    # close capture group 'ip'
      .*                   # match >= 0 characters
    )                      # close capture group 'whole'
    /x                     # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
m = str.match(r)
m[:whole] 
  #=> "Lorem, IP: 111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333\\r\\n adipiscing" 
m[:ip]
  #=> "111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222, 333.333.333.333"
```

The regex is conventionally written:

```
/\A(?<whole>.*?(?<ip>(?<four_threes>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?:, \g<four_threes>)*).*)/
```

When defining a regex in free-spacing mode spaces must be protected in some way, else they will be removed before the expression is parsed. I have used `\p{Space}`, but `[[:space:]]`, `\s` and `[ ]` (a space within a character class) could be used as well. (All but the last match a whitespace character.) When the regex is written in the conventional way a space can be used, as shown above.

`\g<four_threes>` is a [subexpression call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) (search "Subexpression Calls"). Their use saves typing and reduces the chance of errors. If this, the third named capture, is not wanted, it can of course be substituted out.

Comment: Thanks Cary, that covers the multiple IPs part but i also need to capture the whole message in another tag, is there a way to do this with subexpression recall?

Comment: I don't follow. You do have the string in a variable. Is that not straightforward?

Comment: I cannot use a string variable... I updated the ticket maybe it will clear things up a little. message is the whole text but i need to extract the IPs

Comment: `\d{3}` → `\d{1,3}` if you indeed want to match _IP_s.

Comment: @nomad Put the above in parentheses inside `/\A(?<whole>.*?(⇑).*?)\z/` and you are all set.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks, thats exactly what I meant!! I still have an issue with getting all IPs in IP but i am working on it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, good point about `\d{1,3}`. I've been waiting for the OP to confirm your suspicion, but as that has not happened I've made the change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, I added a link to rubular so you can check the results i get. I still dont get all the IPs unfortunately.

Comment: nomad and @AlekseiMatiushkin, I didn't really understand what was wanted until I looked at your (nomad's) revised regex. I've edited my my answer to provide what I now understand is the requirement.

Comment: I fixed that, by just removing the positive lookbehind. As a result I had to make the preceding `.*` non-greedy by changing it to `.*?`. I noticed the end-of-string anchor (`\z`) was not needed (as the final `.*` is greedy), so I removed that.

Comment: I realized i have strings without the 'IP: ...' pattern and i get parsing errors for these ones because it doesnt match.
I was curious to know if there was a way to do something like this 
(IP: ?(?<ip>(?<four_threes>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?:, \g<four_threes>)*) )* 
So this works either there is 0 or more occurences of the pattern

Comment: The final `*` would mean a match could be made if there were no IP's in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/([0-9]_\.)+/` as a very basic regexp (there are much better IPv4 regexp out there).

Then by using `.scan(...)` on your string you will get the results as an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer localhostdotdev but i forgot to mention i am not coding this, so i cant call functions... I use this regex in fluent-bit so I am limited to the regex